# How to create a Schema in slick?

Tags: postgresql

I have searched everywhere but I am unable to find how to create a Schema in slick. I know how to create a table. I want something like this:

```
imdb(SchemaNAME)
----TITLES
----PERSONS
----- ....
```

I have created models for each specific table. I am using Postgres with Slick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue. If this can help, in the table definition, you can specify a schema:

```
Table[T](tag, Some(schemaName), tableName)
```

The create statements then includes the schemaName.

Still looking for creating the schema thought.. At worst, it could be created as a plain query...

```
Something like sqlu"create schema if not exists schemaName"
```